# Calculate the area not being overlapped by other rectangles

Tags: geometry, union, intersection, overlap, rectangles

I have one black rectangle overlapped by other rectangles (please check the attached figure).
Each rectangle is represented by [Top, Left, Bottom, Right] in a 2D coordinate system.

Could someone help me efficiently find the area of yellow regions (inside the black rectangle) that are not overlapped by other (six) rectangles? I am looking for a programming solution (C++).

How can I solve this problem in a general case with more than six rectangles?

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a programming solution or a mathematical solution? What programming language are you using?

Comment: I am looking for a programming solution (C++).

Comment: You can adapt the standard [sweep line algorithm for rectangle union](https://tryalgo.org/en/geometry/2016/06/25/union-of-rectangles/).

Comment: Could you provide your detailed suggestion? I could not understand how to obtain the yellow area (in my question) from **sweep line algorithm for rectangle union**.

Comment: Use the sweep line algorithm to calculate the area of the colored rectangles (appropriately clipped). Subtract that from the area of the black rectangle. The difference is the yellow area.